# Table creation in database isn't happening for excel file upload and store the cell info in database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

The code is working enough to upload an excel file and retrieve data. Need to save the same to the database. connection done but no table created.

> ### cardetails.java

POJO of car entity

```
package com.example3.excelspring;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor; 
import lombok.Builder; 
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
  
@Entity
@Table(name="cardetails")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder 
public class CarDetails {
  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "userId", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private int userId;
    @Column(name = "brand")
    private String brand; 
    @Column(name = "car name")
    private String car_name; 
    @Column(name = "year")
    private int year;
  
  }
```

---

> ExcelspringApplication.java

starter class for spring

```
  package com.example3.excelspring;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;



@SpringBootApplication
public class ExcelspringApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExcelspringApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

> uploadController.java

controller for the excel file upload

```
   package com.example3.excelspring.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;


import com.example3.excelspring.service.UploadService;


@RestController
public class UploadController {
    
    private final UploadService uploadService;
    
    public UploadController(UploadService uploadService) {
        this.uploadService = uploadService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/getAll")
    public List<Map<String, String>> upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception{
        return uploadService.upload(file);
    }
    
    
}
```

> uploadService.java

service to upload excel file

```
package com.example3.excelspring.service;


import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

import com.example3.excelspring.util.UploadUtil;

@Service
public class UploadService {

    @Autowired
    UploadUtil uploadUtil;

    public List<Map<String, String>> upload(MultipartFile file) throws Exception {

        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

        Path tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("");

        File tempFile = tempDir.resolve(file.getOriginalFilename()).toFile();

        file.transferTo(tempFile);

        if (tempFile.isFile() && tempFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Suceess");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Unable to upload");
        }

        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(tempFile);

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Supplier<Stream<Row>> rowStreamSupplier = uploadUtil.getRowStreamSupplier(sheet);

        Row headerRow = rowStreamSupplier.get().findFirst().get();
        List<String> headerCells = uploadUtil.getStream(headerRow)
                .map(Cell::getStringCellValue) 
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        int colCount = headerCells.size();

        List<Map<String, String>> content = rowStreamSupplier.get()
                .skip(1)
                .map(row -> 
                {
                    List<String> cellList = uploadUtil.getStream(row)
                            .map((cell) -> formatter.formatCellValue(cell))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());  
                    return uploadUtil.cellIteratorSupplier(colCount)
                            .get()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(headerCells::get, cellList::get));
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return content;
    }
}
```

> uploadUtil.java

utility class for service class

```
package com.example3.excelspring.util;



import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class UploadUtil {
    

    public Supplier<Stream<Row>> getRowStreamSupplier(Iterable<Row> rows) {
        return () -> getStream(rows);
    }

    public <T> Stream<T> getStream(Iterable<T> iterable) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
    }
    
    public Supplier<Stream<Integer>> cellIteratorSupplier(int end) {
        return () -> numberStream(end);
    }

    public Stream<Integer> numberStream(int end) {
        return IntStream.range(0, end).boxed();
    }
}
```

> application.yml

connections specification

```
server:
  port: 15000

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/car_db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    username: root
    password: Guruji009
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        default_schema: car_db
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        ddl-auto: update
        format_sql: true
        generate_statistics: true
        show_sql: true
        use_sql_comments: true
    database: mysql
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Too much code and too little explanation.

Comment: the issue is i want a table of cardetails to be created in the database automatically..connection is established to MySQL workbench but the table isn't created. not sure where I'm wrong. thanks for the help